# why DependencyResolveDetails is highlight in red

Tags: android

The DependencyResolveDetails is hightlight in red in my app gradle file. 
My android studio is 3.3, how to solve this warning.

```
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And the warning message is :

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'DependencyResolveDetails'
```

Comment: The warning message is : Cannot resolve symbol 'DependencyResolveDetails'

Comment: I've edited the question with the warning message!

Comment: add full build.gradle and logcat

Comment: if you also have `Project#afterEvaluate(Closure) on project ':MyProject' cannot be executed in the current context.` in the build log, try to look into `~/.AndroidStudio3.3/system/log/idea.log` and locate the latest exceptions. try to find the name of a plugin that might be causing problems. mine was OneSignal plugin that I had to update because it used a different version of Gradle plugin. after the update and build, everything was ok. try `./gradlew app:dependencies --stacktrace` also to see if anything shows up

Answer (score 35):

just delete 'DependencyResolveDetails' :

```
configurations.all { //fix ClassNotFoundException : OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "26.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Project build.gradle file, set dependencies to gradle 3.3.0 at least:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error but now resolve

only download the ndk form File -> Project Structure -> and download the ndk

Enjoy the code.